# What's the contraction for non-adjacent fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, linear-algebra, wick-theorem

In section 8.2 of Coleman's QFT lectures, he introduces the definition of contraction of two fields,

[image]

where $T$ denotes time ordering and the colons normal ordering.

Then he proceeds to contraction in normal ordering for fields that are not adjacent,

[image]

Is this a definition? Or how shall I prove it?
Why is it allowed to simply drag the contracted fields out of the normal ordering symbol?

For example, suppose $x>z$, then(I'll use $\bar{}$ symbol to represent contraction)
$$
\begin{aligned}
:\!\bar A(x)B(y)\bar C(z)\!:
&=:\!B(y)\bar A(x)\bar C(z)\!:\\
&=:\!B(y)T[A(x)C(z)]\!:-\boldsymbol:\!B(y)\!
:\!A(x)C(z)\!:\boldsymbol:\\
&=:\!B(y)A(x)C(z)\!:-:\!B(y)A(x)C(z)\!:=0.
\end{aligned}
$$
In the second line, I use bold symbol to distinguish the two pairs of colons. While
$$
\begin{aligned}
:\!B(y)\!:\!\bar A(x)\bar C(z)
&=B(y)A(x)C(z)-B(y)\!:\!A(x)C(z)\!:.
\end{aligned}
$$
If $A(x)$ is in forms like $a(x)a^\dagger(x)$,
the right hand side may not be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-adjacent operators have similar contractions. This can be seen as follows. Recall that everything (super)commutes under a operator ordering symbol, such as, time ordering $T$, normal ordering $:~:$, etc. So one may for free re-order the LHS of OP's 2nd equation $$:ABCD:~ =~ :ACBD:$$ to make operators adjacent and then contract.

Comment: But why is it allowed to drag the contracted fields out of the normal ordering symbol? I edited the question for a counter example.

Comment: A contraction (super)commutes with everything.

Comment: Thank you, I see.